# Apache mod Rewrite: how to rewrite these URLs to make clean URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying do following rewrite from last two days.

1. Force to use www.example.com - **done**
2. Hide PHP extension - **done but not sure that it's a good way**
3. 404 error to custom page - **done**

Now my main problem is

**4. Host all page on root(/)**

I have following files:

```
news.php
search.php
store.php
allstores.php
```

Client requests like this:

```
Type 1: http://www.example.com/news

Type 2: http://www.example.com/search?q=term

Type 3: http://www.example.com/allstores/H

Type 4: http://www.example.com/myname
```

I want to handle these client request like this:

```
Type 1: http://www.example.com/news  ---rewrite to (add extension)-->news.php

Type 2: http://www.example.com/search?q=term  ---->No change, Let it same

Type 3: http://www.example.com/allstores/H --rewrite to --->http://www.example.com/allstores.php?ln=H

Type 4: http://www.example.com/myname ---rewrite to------> http://www.example.com/store?st=myname
```

I have tried following rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*) store.php?st=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^allstores/(.*)$ allstores.php?ln=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Any help is highly appreciable, Thank you

Comment: Look at this post i meade some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003053/how-to-make-nice-rewrited-urls-from-a-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^allstores/([^/]+)/?$ /allstores.php?ln=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /foo to /foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^q=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /store.php?st=$1 [L,QSA]
```