# cleaning url with rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have dirty url like this :

`http://morvaridtour.com/viewtour.php?id=10&title=name-of-tour`
*10 And name-of-tour is dynamic values*

i'm trying to clean that url like this

`http://morvaridtour.com/name-of-tour`

Comment: So value (id) `10` gets discarded?

Comment: This might be duplicate question. Have you referred [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121530/apache-mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-these-urls-to-make-clean-url?rq=1)

Comment: Good for you, hope it goes well, did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file, try something similar like below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^name-of-tour/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ viewtour.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA]
```

Where `$1` is first variable contains only integer `([0-9]+)` and `$2` (title) is second var `(.*)` that accept all characters