# Rewrite rule parameter in combination with file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting

There is the daily question again, how can I rewrite my .htaccess. I found there is a lack of information about the .htaccess rules and can not find an answer to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Now this rule makes sure that users.php?username=hello rewrites as user.php/hello
but how can I get rid of the .php? Do i add the following condition and change the previous condition without the .php? so

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user?username=$1 [L]
```

Or do I keep the previous one WITH php? I found the following condition to remove the php.

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

however it is NOT working in combination with the user.php.

How can I rewrite user.php?username=hello to user/hello and in the same time have normal .php files as index.php to index.

Comment: The general pattern is `Directive regex substitution flags`, the substitution should normally be a relative path to a file, unless you are going to rewrite the result again in another rule. Have you tried removing the leading `/` from the substitution? The `.php` is already "gone" because URLs wont need to contain it.

Comment: Removing the / from which line of code?

Comment: All of the substitutions, as per the general pattern in my previous comment.

Comment: Removing the / from all of the substitutions does not work.

Comment: Based on your question  "How can I rewrite user.php?username=hello to user/hello", it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of rewriting, it's the other way around. Rewriting is so that URLs that match the regex pattern will actually go to the substitution. The `user.php` would not appear in the URL in your browser's address bar. If you want to redirect, then that's different.

Comment: No, I would like to rewrite a parameter, not redirect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache mod Rewrite: how to rewrite these URLs to make clean URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121530/apache-mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-these-urls-to-make-clean-url)